# Using Stash to Pull Matrix Data from a Related Entry?

Tags: stash

I am trying to expand some code suppled by Mark Croxton in [another thread](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/433/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-a-matrix-field-in-stash/1992#1992) to create a list of Matrix results from a related entry but without success. This is with Stash 2.3.5 on ExpressionEngine 2.5.3.

Here is my SET code from my main template:

```
    {exp:stash:set_list name="landing_slideshow" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}

      {exp:channel:entries channel="slideshow" sort="date" dynamic="no" disable="member_data|pagination" parse="inward"}

        {stash:stash_entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:stash_entry_id}
        {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
        {stash:landing_slideshow_image}{landing_page_slideshow_image}{/stash:landing_slideshow_image}

        {exp:stash:set_list:nested name="lb_slideshow_credits_{entry_id}" parse_tags="yes"}
          {related_entries id="related_work_project"}
            {work_team}
              {stash:lp_slideshow_position}{mx_position}{/stash:lp_slideshow_position}
              {stash:lp_slideshow_person}{mx_person}{/stash:lp_slideshow_person}
            {/work_team}
          {/related_entries}
        {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}

      {/exp:channel:entries}

    {/exp:stash:set_list}
```

And here is the GET code I have in an embeded template:

```
  {exp:stash:get_list name="landing_slideshow"}
    <ul class="normal">
      <li>{stash_entry_id}</li>
      {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="lb_slideshow_credits_{entry_id}"}
        <li><span class="">{lp_slideshow_position} | </span> {lp_slideshow_person}</li>
      {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
    </ul>
  {/exp:stash:get_list}
```

The Stashed values set outside the {related_entries} loop — {stash_entry_id}, {title} and {landing_slideshow_image} are all displaying as expected. Nothing in the {related_entries} loop is displaying or appears to be stashed.

Does using related entries change things enough that [answers in the other thread](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/433/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-a-matrix-field-in-stash/1992#1992) aren't applicable?

Comment: Are you using the latest Matrix? There was a bug in an older version that prevented it being captured by Stash. That aside, it looks like you actually need 3 levels of nested lists, since there may be multiple related entries and multiple matrix rows per related entry.

Comment: Well, there will be 8-10 entires in the slideshow channel, but each entry will have one related entry and, yes, the Matrix field will have multiple rows. 

Where would the third set_list go? I tried placing it just inside {work_team} — so a new set_list for each Matrix field — but that seemed to break all Stash parsing.

I just upgraded from Matrix 2.5.1 to 2.5.2.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by removing Stash from the equation and instead using two {exp:channel:entries} tag. After 53 views of this question, my assumption is this is not a common use for Stash and thus the tradeoff between performance and supporting my own code 6 months down the line is low.

Comment: Can you make sure to select your answer as the correct one by clicking on the checkmark to the left.

Comment: I woud @AnnaBrown_MediaGirl, but I'm not sure if that is a correct answer — I didn't have time to mess with it any longer — but it was more tossing my hands in the air and giving up. Would be nice to know if this were actually possible but that's academic for me.